# with open nested loop in selenium isn't working

Tags: python, selenium

it's my first time posting here, so please let me know if I've messed anything up. I'm having some trouble with a nested loop in selenium. I'm trying to iterate through a list of players, gather stats for each one, and add them to a dataframe. Right now each player in the list gets entered into the search bar and their page is displayed, but stats are only collected for the last player in the list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get(url)

dataframe1 = []

with open('A.txt') as f:
    players = f.readlines()
    for player in players:
        search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search")
        search.send_keys(player)
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header"]/div[3]/form/input[1]')
        button.click()
        stats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passing"]/tfoot/tr')
        for stat in stats:
            comps = stat.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passing"]/tfoot/tr/td[6]').text
            data = {
                    'Player': player,
                    'Completions': comps,
            }

            dataframe1.append(data)

  df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe1)

  print(df)
  driver.close()
```

Comment: 1) _list of players_: An example? 2) _gather stats_: Which stat are you looking for from [player page](https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/blake-bosma-1.html)

Comment: Hello, for a list of players example, I'm just using a text file with each players first and last name followed by a new line. Right now I'm just trying to get it to work with 2 players, I'm using Joe Montana and Warren Moon. The stat I'm trying to collect off the page is total completions.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentation for the lines where you initialize the data dict, and append to `dataframe1`. they must be at the same level as the block under the innermost *for* loop.
I modified your code, here:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get(url)

dataframe1 = []

with open('A.txt') as f:
    players = f.readlines()
    for player in players:
        search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search")
        search.send_keys(player)
        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header"]/div[3]/form/input[1]')
        button.click()
        stats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passing"]/tfoot/tr')
        for stat in stats:
            comps = stat.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passing"]/tfoot/tr/td[6]').text
            data = {
                'Player': player,
                'Completions': comps,
            }

            dataframe1.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe1)

print(df)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Maaddy. I've corrected my code based off of your example. Really appreciate the help! I'm still having the issue though where my script is only gather stats for the last player in the list.

Comment: if `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passing"]/tfoot/tr')` returns an empty list for one player, no stats will be added to `dataframe1`. So try `print(stats)` just before the innermost for loop, and see what you get for each player. you will notice that one of them has an empty list (probably)

Comment: There more efficient way to do this without Selenium. Mind sharing your `A.txt` file, or a sample of it to show you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your assistance with this issue. I eventually found out that I did not need the 'button' variable or button.click() in the script. Send keys was already hitting "return" after the string was passed to the search parameter on the page, so basically return was getting hit twice, once on the players name, and once on an empty search parameter. The default page that was returned when searching for the empty parameter did not contain the element I was attempting to find, which resulted in an empty list. Again thank you for your help with this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).